# SQL return results for Table A, based on criteria from Table B

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables which share a 1 to many relationship. Assume the following structure:

```
users             users_metadata
-------------     -------------
id | email        id | user_id | type | score
```

A user can have many metadata. The users table has 100k rows, the users_metadata table has 300k rows. It'll likely grow 10x so whatever I write needs to be optimal for large amounts of data.

**I need to write a sql statement that returns only user emails that pass a couple of different score conditions found in the metadata table.**

```
// if type = 1 and if score > 75 then <1 point> else <0 points>
// if type = 2 and if score > 100 then <1 point> else <0 points>
// if type = 3 and if score > 0 then [-10 points] else <0 points>

// there are other types that we want to ignore in the score calculations
```

If the user passes a threshold (e.g. >= 1 point) then I want that user to be in the resultset, otherwise I want the user to be ignored.

I have tried user a stored function/cursor that takes a user_id and loops over the metadata to figure out the points, but the resulting execution was very slow (although it did work).

As it stands I have this, and it takes about 1 to 3 seconds to execute.

```
SELECT u.id, u.email,

    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(
                IF(k.type = 1, IF(k.score > 75, 1, 0), 0) + 
                IF(k.type = 2, IF(k.score > 100, 1, 0), 0) +
                IF(k.type = 3, IF(k.score > 0, 1, -10), 0)
            ) 
        FROM user_metadata k WHERE k.user_id = u.id
        
    ) AS total

FROM users u GROUP BY u.id HAVING total IS NOT NULL;
```

I feel like at 10x this is going to be even slower. a 1 to 3 second query execution time is too slow for what I need already.

What would a more optimal approach be?

If I use a language like PHP for this too, would running 2 queries, one to fetch `user_ids` from `user_metadata` of only `passing` users, and then a second to SELECT WHERE IN on that list of ids be better?

Comment: This is a reporting-type query that will need to scan millions of rows. You cannot expect this query to run extremely fast.

Comment: That's fair. If 1 to 3s is acceptable for as fast as it can run, then I'm OK with that. I'll go with @Barmar's solution below so I can easier run conditional checks. I can limit the results down to 25 and only show per page, therefore the query should be acceptable (< 500ms) for the admin page loading this info.

Comment: Actually the join method on a limited selection is FAR slower than my nested select query above. The JOIN takes 500ms to run the query on 25 results. The nested select takes 32ms

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, plus the approximate size of each table.  Since `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can make a _big_ difference in optimization, please provide the full query!  Your timings show that!

Comment: What is the distribution of `type`?  Are the values only 1,2,3?  If not, what percentage are not 1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: 1, 2 or 3 are the only ones I care about. This may expand to 4s, 5s, 6s or 7s at a later date. There are other types, but only the first 3 are relevant, and the most numerous. At a guess maybe 50% are the other types.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, I can ORDER BY type on the inner query (join as it is now), limit further with a HAVING on the internal query, and then LIMIT the entire output to 25 as the final results are going to be paged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a JOIN instead of correlated subquery.

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, t.total
FROM users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(CASE type
        WHEN 1 THEN score > 75
        WHEN 2 THEN score > 100
        WHEN 3 THEN IF(k.score > 0, 1, -10)
        END) AS total
    FROM user_metadata
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING total >= 1
) AS t ON u.id = t.user_id
```

Doing the grouping and filtering in the subquery makes the join smaller, which can be a significant performance boost.

There's also no need for you to use `GROUP BY u.id` in your query, since that's the primary key of the table you're querying; hopefully MySQL will optimize that out.

Comment: Thanks, With this query, first row is available after 500ms, It still takes just over 1s to run this. The query I wrote first row is available at 90ms, but seems to take around the same total execution time.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't that also need a `HAVING sum(...) >= 1` in the derived table to filter ineligible users? (Or a `WHERE t.total >= 1` in the outer query. But it seems preferable to keep the set in the derived table as small as possible.)

Comment: There won't be any zero sums in the subquery, so those rows won't join.

Comment: @Barmar: Then the inner query is wrong all together. They want to calculate a sum of calculated scores and since there can be scores of `0` or even `-10`, the sum of the scores can well be `0` or even negative... You just counted the occurrences when a condition was met, as I see now (I overlooked that.). You don't sum the scores associated with the conditions.

Comment: @Barmar: Correction: I should have better written "They want to calculate a sum of calculated points [from conditions in scores]" at least that's their naming and keeps the scores the calculations are based on phonetically separate from the points (actually also some sort of scores) the calculations yield.

Comment: The original query has `HAVING total IS NOT NULL`. So it's not filtering out zero scores, it's filtering out players who have no scores at all in `user_metadata`. The same thing happens with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar: True, the filter is only in their text: "If the user passes a threshold (e.g. >= 1 point) then I want that user to be in the resultset, otherwise I want the user to be ignored.". But the original query *does* sum expressions like `IF(k.type = 3, IF(k.score > 0, 1, -10), 0)` which also corresponds to their text "`if type = 3 and if score > 0 then [-10 points] else <0 points>`". And if there was a filter in the inner query that might reduce its result set, having the overall query less rows to join.

Comment: Thanks, missed that text. I've updated the query.

Comment: I think I can fabricate data with a zero score from 11 rows, one of which counts as -10.  Weird.

Comment: This got more discussion than I thought it would! Thanks for the input everyone. I ended up going for the join here. You were right in that I didn't care about users who didn't score a passing mark. so if the pass mark = 1, then I only want to see users who have a score >=1 . And yea you're right about scores. the "score" is a number in the database, I use "points" to differentiate, and for example, if you get `score > 75`, you get 1 point. Each condition equates to 1 point, or 0 points. One specific condition equates to -10 points (thats a custom thing)

Comment: Marked as correct as it did answer the question, but I do still find it's a slower query than the one I originally had. Although I should try it with the inner HAVING to see if that makes a big difference (I suspect it will)

Comment: @RickJames you could indeed get 0 from 11 rows in user_metadata. That is what we want. The reason being is that type 3 is technically an override that forces a full failure. However we only have 2 - 4 different types so the -10 was just a safe barrier to ensure at least 0 or less for the user if they have a type 3 set.